# How would I find the row and column length of this matrix? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, nested

I'm given a matrix from a file that looks like this:

```
1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0

1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 G 0
```

The goal is to be able to read in the matrix to another function and also find the row and column length. I'm also not trying to import any additional libraries. Here's what I have so far:

```
    with open('matrix.txt','r') as txt:
        data = txt.readlines()

    for row in data:
        print(row)
        for column in row:
            print(column)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('matrix.txt','r') as txt:
    data = txt.readlines()

data=[l.strip() for l in data if len(l)>1]
print (data)
['1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0',
 '0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0',
 '0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0',
 '0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0',
 '0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0',
 '0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0',
 '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0',
 '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0',
 '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0',
 '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0',
 '1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 G 0']

print("length of the row is:",len(data))
print("length of the columns is:",len(data[0].split()))

length of the row is: 11
length of the columns is: 16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    row  = 0
    for line in fp:
        if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
            continue
        row += 1
    arr = list(map(str,line.split(' ')))
    col = len(arr)

print(row,col)
```

For each line we are incrementing `row` counter and for `col` we are checking how many characters are there in one line by splitting the line according to separator : ' ' .